# C++, Member function returning const reference to vector containing pointers to const objects

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, return, constants

I have a class with a member vector of pointers to objects. Now I want an accessor method to return a const reference to this vector. I also want the caller method to be unable to edit the objects pointed to by the vector's pointers, i.e. the pointers should point to const objects. Here is my erroneous code:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    vector<Foo*> myFoos;
public:
    const vector<const Foo*> &getMyFoos(void)
    {
        return myFoos; //Doesn't work since vector<Foo*> cannot be cast to vector<const Foo*>
    }
}
```

I have seen answers to similar questions where the solution is to make a copy of the vector myFoos where the copy is of the correct type. Is there anyway to do this without making a copy, since the myFoos vector may be very large?

Comment: You could return `static_cast<Foo const *>(myFoos.data())` if the result will only be used for a short time, before you mutate the vector...

Comment: Reason #84962 why I don't use C++: `vector<Foo>` can't be cast to `vector<const Foo>`. @KerrekSB Good suggestion.

Comment: Return a pair of const iterators to begin and end.  In C++11 teach `for` how to iterate over it as well.

Comment: @H2CO3: then you add a `const Foo` to your cast-to `vector`, and still later access it via the original `vector` and try changing it... BOOM.

Comment: @KerrekSB Am I right that this would return an array as opposed to a vector? So I'd also have to return the size of the vector through a parameter?

Comment: @KerrekSB and thank you, this was driving me nuts

Comment: Or use a type to wrap the pointers, where `operator*` and `operator->` have adequate `const` versions.

Comment: Add a method to access the objects, instead of the vector: `Foo const* getFoo(size_t i) const { return myFoos[i]; }` -- Also a method to get the size.  If your pointers cannot be null, return a reference instead.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ahh this is perfect, didn't even think of it. Thanks.

Comment: This is pretty gross but I'll post it for the sake of discussion: `return *reinterpret_cast< const vector<const Foo*>* >(&myFoos);`

Comment: @H2CO3 I agree, and find this "casting" restriction of C++ very annoying.  The std committee should run with the idea of SCARY iterators (permitting more flexible type assignment) and apply to all types generally.  Or, perhaps a yield generator concept like C# has...

Answer (score 0):

Just add `operator[] const` to your `Foo` class:

```
const Foo& operator[] (size_t i) const {
    // you may add some range checking here
    return *myFoos[i];
}
```